# Understanding EOF

Tags: c, arrays, eof

I have a function that scans doubles from a file into separate arrays, where the doubles alternate in which array they're scanned in.

It works for the most part, but I also want to add the ability to count how many doubles are scanned regardless of the ARR_SIZE, so I can display a warning of how many doubles were not used to increment the sigSize counters above 1500.

My attempt was just to remove the ARR_SIZE stuff from the condition, or move it, so I can just add the third counter, but that makes my results wrong. Also if I type in inputs with my keyboard, instead of from the file, it automatically increments to 1500.

Overall I just seem to lack a definite understanding of how to use EOF, and any help would be appreciated!

ARR_SIZE is 1500

```
Size read_array(double array1[], double array2[])
{
    Size size = {0, 0};

    int i = 0;

    int status1 = 0;
    int status2 = 0;

    while(size.sigSize1 < ARR_SIZE && size.sigSize2 < ARR_SIZE && 
         (status1 != EOF || status2 != EOF))
    {

        status1 = scanf("%lf", &array1[i]);

        if(status1 != EOF)
        {
            size.sigSize1++;
        }        

        status2 = scanf("%lf", &array2[i]);

        if(status2 != EOF)
        {
            size.sigSize2++;
        }

        i++;

    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Understanding EOF

The `scanf()` function reports how many values it successfully assigned, or EOF if it encountered EOF before reading anything else.

The correct way to test here is `if (status1 != 1)` which protects against stray alphanumerics or other non-numeric characters in the input.  At the moment, your code would loop indefinitely, eventually crashing, rather than spot the problem.

#### Fixing the code

Since this isn't an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), we have to guess about the contents of the `Size` type.  However, we can handle things more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct Size
{
    int sigSize1;
    int sigSize2;
    int sigSize3;
    int sigSize4;
} Size;

enum { ARR_SIZE = 15 };  // 1500 per question

static Size read_array(double array1[], double array2[])
{
    Size size = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++)
    {
        double d;

        int status1 = scanf("%lf", &d);

        if (status1 != 1)
            break;
        if (i < ARR_SIZE)
        {
            array1[i] = d;
            size.sigSize1++;
        }
        else
            size.sigSize3++;

        int status2 = scanf("%lf", &d);

        if (status2 != 1)
            break;
        if (i < ARR_SIZE)
        {
            array2[i] = d;
            size.sigSize2++;
        }
        else
            size.sigSize4++;
    }

    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a1[ARR_SIZE];
    double a2[ARR_SIZE];
    Size size = read_array(a1, a2);
    printf("In a1: %d; in a2: %d; missed from a1: %d; missed from a2: %d\n",
           size.sigSize1, size.sigSize2, size.sigSize3, size.sigSize4);
    return 0;
}
```

Given a data file (`data3`):

```
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
12.13  19.24
35.43
```

the output from the program (`xs`) was:

```
$ ./xs < data3 | so
In a1: 9; in a2: 8; missed from a1: 0; missed from a2: 0
$ cat data3 data3 data3 data3 data3 | ./xs | so
In a1: 15; in a2: 15; missed from a1: 28; missed from a2: 27
$
```